# LibGDX - Ending a Level and breaking out of Render()

Tags: libgdx

The basic idea of the game is to collect all the items in a room in order to proceed to the next. Not very original I know... When the items are all collected, a screen will be displayed stating "Level Complete" and then after a few seconds the next level will be reloaded. The problem I am having is that when I land on the last item, and the check "have all the items been collected?" rule is satisfied the game suddenly freezes, well starts to shake actually. The player sprite is frozen in place, as is the item, and the game can no longer be interacted with. I can only assume that the game is getting trapped inside the render() method and is not escaping, or is satisfying the same condition over again.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to break out of the main render() method correctly to traverse to a new screen?

In my main render() method I have a call to another method which checks the gamestate, ie, have all of the items been collected in the room...

```
render() {

    ... code ...
    checkGameState()
}
```

And then checkGameState() looks as follows:

```
public void checkGameState() 
{

    //If the player has collected all of the items on a level then do something
    //if(stats.getItemsCollected() == stats.getTotalItems()) {
        //reset some stuff
        stats.resetItems();
        stats.incLevel();

        //show the intermediate screen or menu screen

        //load the next level
        showLevelCompleteScreen();


        //

    }
}
```

The ShowLevelCompleteScreen() method simply attempts to switch screens as follows:

```
public void showLevelComplete()
{
    game.setScreen(SuperBlockMan.LevelComplete);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I'd advise you to not reset your Screen, but to `dispose()` it correctly and then create a completely new one after one level finished. That saves you from bugs due to incorrect resetting.

After you switched the Screen to LevelComplete, the rendering will not stop, but libGDX will start to call render of your LevelComplete Screen.

As for the freezing of your character, item and so on, I guess you do not call `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` in the render method of your LevelComplete Screen and that's why you can still see everything from your game, but cannot interact anymore.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I do have the Gdx.gl.glclear stuff you suggested in my render method of the other screen, so I guess it must be down to disposal. Problem is, I don't fully understand this. The GameScreen implements Screen, as does the LevelComplete screen. I assume this is OK, but how do you dispose a screen correctly. I understand that the hide() method may be being called, but am unsure what to do with it. I am really struggling to find any examples which are not overly complicated or rely on Scene2D etc. It must be possible to switch screens surely??

Comment: The call to `setScreen` will result in the `Game` class switching the screen after the current iteration. It will result in a call to hide() and a call to show(). Dispose must be called by yourself when you do setScreen. when you use a Stage, you should remember to switch the InputProcessor. Without more code it's a pure guessing game what you might do wrong or forgot to do...